# What are the syntax rules for the Google ngrams search engine?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

In this [Google Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pimienta+de+cayena%2Cchile+de+cayena&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true), I was trying to determine which of the following two phrases occurs most often in Spanish literature. However, I must have misspelled something or used the wrong delimiters to separate the two phrases:

> - pimienta de cayena
> - chile de cayena

However, only results for "**pimienta de cayena**" are visible.

How do I show "**chile de cayena**" on the same chart?

[image: screen capture of Google Books Ngram Viewer with pimienta de cayena,chile de cayena]

If I am searching for an entire phrase, instead of one word, do I have to wrap the phrase in quotation marks?

What is the correct syntax?

`pimienta de cayena,chile de cayena`

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is correct, but evidently there are [too few hits in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chile%20de%20cayena%22&lr=lang_es&tbs=lr%3Alang_1es&tbm=bks) (I count 11) to put "chile de cayena" on the graph. Meanwhile "mata de cayena" for example has 23 which is just barely enough for Google Books. (Alternatively, some hits found by searching Google Books directly may not even be in the Ngrams corpus, which was last updated in 2019.) I used an [alternative web interface](https://www.english-corpora.org/googlebooks/) for the Google Books corpora, and it also didn't return any results for *chile de cayena*.

I also searched [Corpus del Español](https://www.corpusdelespanol.org/web-dial/), and *chile de cayena* occurs 0 times in its 2 billion words.